# Why is my home page component rendering on every route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a recipes app and the component I've built for the home page is rendering on every other route (or page). I'll click to go to the random recipe component I've built, and lo and behold, my home page component is rendered beneath it. This is the case with all of my routes.

How can I make it so the home page component doesn't render on every other page?

```
import React from 'react';
import hero from './cuttingboard.jpg';
import cooking from './random.jpeg';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">
        <div className="hero">
          <img className="cuttingboard" src={hero}></img>
          <h1>Find recipes</h1>
          <div className="hero-p">
            <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, recusandae voluptatem ullam commodi perspiciatis, quod libero totam esse odio voluptas culpa dolore cum molestiae voluptates tempore, numquam corrupti ipsum similique.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="hero-features">
            <h1>Browse recipes to your hearts' extent</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="home-random">
          <img src={cooking}></img>
          <Link to='/random'>
          <h1>Get random meal</h1>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Meals from './Meal';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import RandomRecipe from './RandomRecipe';
import Home from './Home'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() { 


  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="content">
       <Nav />
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/meals" exact component={Meals}/>
        <Route path="/random" exact component={RandomRecipe}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Home />
    </Router>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It needs its own route

Comment: To expand upon @JBallin's comment, you need to bring `<Home />` into the `<Switch>...</ Switch>` section. You can place it below without a `<Route />` for implicit routing (since you're using a `<Switch>`, it will always only pick the first valid component), or if you want you can put it in a `<Route />` component if you want to have a 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not defining seperate route for Home component
The below code shall solve your problem. The Home component is rendering on every route because you haven't defined in a Route as you did for other components.
Happy Learning!!

```
    <Router>
      <div className="content">
       <Nav />
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/meals" exact component={Meals}/>
        <Route path="/random" exact component={RandomRecipe}/>
        <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```